# Installing software while running bootable usb

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am new to Linux so I have created a bootable usb drive with Linux Mint on it so that I can play around with it for a while before deciding if I want to install Linux on my harddrive.

I have created the pendrive with persistence so that I should have the ability to install software on it. However I can't seem to install anything.

I have downloaded the graphical linux postgresql installation file, given it execution permissions and then get the following error when I try to run it:

```
There has been an error
Error changing ownership of
/tmp/postgresql_installer_120403f9ba/lib/postgresql to root
```

I also downloaded the 7zip tar file, extracted it and tried to run the install.sh file. But nothing happens. Im just trying to see if I can get anything to install.

Im guessing either there's something with permissions that im not doing correctly, or it has something to do with the fact that im running linux from a usb drive.

As mentioned, im brand new to linux.

Comment: Not much we can say about permissions, since you do not tell us what you really did. Apart from that, why don't you install the packages as provided for your distribution, but instead apparently try to make a "wild" install of postgresql right into the file system? This is exactly how software should _not_ be installed in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your elitist response. I have made it clear I am brand new to linux and trying to learn. Anyway, I have figured it out myself.

Comment: I am sorry if I upset you. That certainly was not my intention. You are absolutely right that you made clear that you are new to Linux and that is absolutely fine. Welcome. But you got my comment completely wrong. I wrote it to find out _why_ you install that way. That is what I wrote, not more. Reason is: you already installed the distribution, so we can assume you know how to do that, how to install packages in Linux (you _did_ it). We also can assume you have a very good understanding of IT stuff. So _why_ do you try to install this package different? That was all my intention. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what was required. I was trying to double click the install file from the GUI which wasn't working. I had to run it using sudo from the command line. Looks good now.